# Add shape to a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` and I wanna add a circle shape in the middle of it.
how can I do that?

Here's what I want to achieve.
[image]

Thanks/

Comment: use UIimage ....

Comment: yes ! use image !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a subview in your button

```
let circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleDimension, height: circleDimension)
let circle = UIView(frame: circleFrame)
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
circle.layer.borderWidth = circleWidth
circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
circle.layer.cornerRadius = circleDimension/2
```

Just add that as a subview to your button and set centerX and centerY anchors equal to your button. Then, if you want to make it square, just do

```
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this including using CoreGraphics. The easiest way is to  just set an image on the button

[How to set image of UIButton in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296772/how-to-set-image-of-uibutton-in-swift-3)

If you need it clickable ofcourse, otherwise just use a UIImageView(which you can also make clickable using `UITapGestureRecognizer`)

Comment: I want to change the circle shape to square later on base on tap, so I need be something dynamic, not an image.

Comment: You can change set the selected and unselected image and just change the button selected, the image will change automatically

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage set the image for both .normal and .selected and then toggle state on user tap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22883654/2585955 here's an example. i would edit the question to include this so that I can add this in my answer